# JAXB Unmarshalling of bad XML does not throw exception

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshal an XML string that does not match the JAXB class.  I expected this to throw an exception, but instead, a new JAXB object is returned.

xmlStr (Input XML)

```
<urn1:RgBad
    xmlns:urn1="urn:none">
</urn1:RgBad>
```

Correct XML

```
<urn:Rg
    xmlns:urn="urn:test"
```

Code

```
(clazz = Rg.class)
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlStr));
    //Returns an actual Rg object, even though the source root element and namespace are different.
    (unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, clazz)).getValue();
```

Comment: You should add schema validation in JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your schema to verify your xml file when using JAXB

```
try {  
  SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);  
  Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new  File( "yourSchema.xsd" ));  
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz.getPackage().getName());  
  Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();  
  u.setSchema(schema);  
  u.setEventHandler(ehdler);  

  obj = u.unmarshal(xml);  
} catch  (JAXBException e) {
} finally  {  
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping not to have to do schema validation, but I supposed validation must be all or nothing with JAXB unmarshalling.